# Can not manage to create new column in with the correct index

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I'm following a sample TypeScript code proposed by Microsoft and adapting it to my needs.
For context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-cross-reference

There is a code block written in the sample as follows

```
// Log the event data to the console and return it for a flow.
let stringResult = JSON.stringify(records);
console.log(stringResult);
return stringResult;
```

But I get some warning in the code editor about this.

> Can not find name let.

Its like its not recognizing I'm declaring a variable. Let works in all other places.

> Can not find stringResult".
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ScreenedOutCompany'.

When I run the Script I get errors in the console about this code block.

```
>Line #23: ',' expected.
 let stringResult = JSON.stringify(records)
Line #23: ')' expected.
 let stringResult = JSON.stringify(records)
Line #38: '}' expected.
 }
```

Not sure what is wrong here.
Also I'm wondering if its necessary to log the entire data in the console at all or if the "return" function of the variable can work without the previous logging in the console.

Comment: Bizarre, I took the script and it compiles for me without issue.  I haven't replicated the entire worksheet but if I change out the sheet name, it runs without error.  Have you edited the example code?  If so, can you paste the entire script into your question?

Comment: Hello @Skin thanks for looking into it.

It seems that I was missing a `}` at the end of that code block. Since I have it here I no longer get that issue. So basically I was not closing out the entire first part of the script.